# index out of range exception was unhandled in c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

This is my code to retrieve currently inserted product_ID but i got the exception here - "Index Out of range" Product_ID

```
    public int GetProductIDD()
    {
        int productID = 0;

        con.Open();
        string str = "SELECT MAX(Product_ID) FROM AddProduct";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rd.Read())
        {
            productID = Convert.ToInt32(rd["Product_ID"]);
        }

        return productID;
    }
```

My database table AddProduct as follows-

```
Product_ID   Product_Name  Vendor_ID
-----------------------------------------
1            asd           3
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you sure that you're query is correct? Which output do you get when you run it on SQL Server directly?

Comment: yes query is right i got the o/p as 1 when query is executed on sql server

Comment: The problem is that your output doesn't contain a column named "ProducT_ID". Execute the query on SQL Server and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Beyond that... why are you attempting to get this information anyways?  Doing stuff like this is often indicative of problematic design or misconceptions about data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with alias name:

```
string str = "SELECT MAX(Product_ID) as Product_ID FROM AddProduct";
```

**Analysis:**

With your query, the result will be something like:

```
MAX(Product_ID)
1
```

And you are trying to fetch `Product_ID` field from the result.

With alias name, the result will be like:

```
Product_ID
1
```

Comment: but what's exactly error in my code as it gets o/p on sql server

Comment: See the analysis part.

Answer (score -1):

If your Query returning the single result it should be the correct Out put as well in C# OutPut.

Check for your data Reader which have entry first .

```
if (rd.HasRows)
{
    while (rd.Read())
    {
        productID = Convert.ToInt32(rd["Product_ID"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Op found answer and accepted as well

Comment: no problem . take it like a suggestion. I dont have enough reputation to comment now thats y